# A rigorous proof of a trigonometric inequality in $(0,\pi/2)$

Tags: inequality, trigonometric-series

I want to show
$$f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{2 x}{17}\right)-8 \sin
   \left(\frac{4 x}{17}\right)+27 \sin
   \left(\frac{6 x}{17}\right)-64 \sin
   \left(\frac{8 x}{17}\right)+125 \sin
   \left(\frac{10 x}{17}\right)-216 \sin
   \left(\frac{12 x}{17}\right)+343 \sin
   \left(\frac{14 x}{17}\right)-512 \sin
   \left(\frac{16 x}{17}\right)<0,\quad x\in(0,\pi/2).$$
This trigonometric inequality has been verified by Mathematica using the Plot commend. I found $f$ can be rewritten

$$f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{2 x}{17}\right)-2^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*2 x}{17}\right)+3^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*3 x}{17}\right)-4^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*4 x}{17}\right)+5^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*5 x}{17}\right)-6^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*6 x}{17}\right)+7^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*7 x}{17}\right)-8^3 \sin
   \left(\frac{2*8 x}{17}\right)<0,\quad x\in(0,\pi/2).$$
However, I cannot give a rigorous proof of it. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Why on earth do you want to show this? There are going to be infinite inequalities of this type... What makes this one special?

Comment: It's worth noting that each term is of the form $(-1)^{n-1} n^3 \sin\left(\frac{2nx}{17}\right) $ for $n\in \{1,2,3,...,8\} $

Comment: If I had to guess at a proof outline, I would say that we should first look at properties of the infinite sum and then analyze what happens when cut off the sum at a given finite point. Might also be useful to analyze properties of $\sin\left(\frac{2nx}{17}\right)$, as the $17$ in the denominator is interesting (recall Guass' construction of the $17$-gon and its relation to the Sine function!)

Comment: In particular, note that $\begin{align} 16\,\operatorname{cos}{2\pi\over17} = & -1+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}+ \\ & 2\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}- \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}- 2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}. \end{align}$. Not sure if this has any relation to the summation at hand, but was too interesting to me to not look up and post :)

Comment: It looks like "the fourth derivative" of the classical Fejer-Jackson inequality. I would start from revisiting a couple of proofs of the FJI and checking if they fits or not the given situation.

Comment: $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1} $$ is the Fourier series of a rectangle wave and $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \sin(n x)}{n} $$ is the Fourier series of a triangle wave.

Comment: In fact, I want to show more general $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{j+1} j^3\sin\Big(\frac{2j}{2k+1}x\Big)<0$ for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @LCH: you need an extra assumption on the parity of $k$ but that is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, that is easier than expected. If we define
$$ C_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k k^3\sin\left(\frac{2kx}{2n+1}\right)\tag{1} $$
through $\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$ we have:
$$\small{ C_n(x) = -\frac{i (-1)^n}{2z^n (1+z)^4}\left(3 n^2 z (1+z)^2 \left(-1+z^{2 n}\right)+z (1-4z+z^2)\left(-1+z^{2 n}\right)-3 n z \left(-1+z^2\right) \left(1+z^{2 n}\right)+n^3 (1+z)^3 \left(-1+z^{1+2 n}\right)\right)}\tag{2} $$
with $z=\exp\left(\frac{2ix}{2n+1}\right)$. Such explicit formula gives that $C_n(x)$ and $(-1)^n$ have the same sign on the interval $(0,\pi)$. So $(1)$ really is an uglier but simpler version of the Fejer-Jackson inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the argument. So the key is to use the Euler formula. The fact that $C_n(x)$ and $(-1)^n$ have the same sign on the interval $(0,\pi)$ solves the desired inequality? It seems to me that it only solves for even $n$?

Comment: @LCH: well, in the original problem $n=8$, and in the original sum there is a $(-1)^{k\color{red}{+1}}$ term. The given inequality is reversed for odd values of $n$.

Comment: Yes! I see. I didn't notice that the given inequality is reversed for odd $n$.

Comment: By the way, in what sensei would you say (1) is a simpler version of the Fejer-Jackson inequality?

Comment: @LCH: different weights ($(-1)^k k^3$ instead of $\frac{1}{k}$) and simpler proof.

Comment: I see. Then perhaps we may call it Fejer-Jackson type inequality.

Comment: I'm curious if we can in some sense generalize the inequality (1) or not.

Comment: Since $\sin x$ is monotonically increasing in $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, an easy observation gives $\sin \left(\frac{2 x}{17}\right)-8 \sin\left(\frac{4 x}{17}\right)<0$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$. Accordingly, the original inequality trivially holds:p. The more general inequality holds, too.